# How to calculate ratio in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table hw1 like this:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| budget | price  | count(*) |
+--------+--------+----------+
| high   | high   |        9 |
| high   | low    |       13 |
| high   | medium |       20 |
| low    | high   |       60 |
| low    | low    |       94 |
| low    | medium |      162 |
| medium | high   |      151 |
| medium | low    |      228 |
| medium | medium |      355 |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

and I would like to add another column on the right which looks like `"count(*)/budget` sample size"

For example, for row one `where budget = high and price = high`,
we would get a number `calculated by 9/42` (42 is high budget sample size= [9 + 13 + 20])

I have tried the following code but the result is `null`

```
select (select count(*) from hw1 where count(*) like 'a%') / 
(select count(*) from hw1 where budget like 'b%') from hw1;
```

I believe this is not hard but I cannot get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another query to get the "budget sample size" for each value of `budget`, and then use the result from that query as a row source.

(Absent a definition of the table and example data, we're just guessing at the query you would use to get that.)

```
  SELECT r.budget
       , COUNT(*) AS budget_sample_size
    FROM hw1 r
   GROUP BY r.budget
```

We expect that query would return a result with one row per value of `budget`, e.g.

```
  budget  budget_sample_size
  ------  ------------------
  high                    42
  low                    316 
  medium                 734
```

The trick now is to use that query as a rowsource in another query. We wrap that query in parens, and reference it in the FROM clause of another query, as if it were a table.  As a simple example...

```
SELECT s.budget
     , s.budget_sample_size
  FROM ( 
         SELECT r.budget
              , COUNT(*) AS budget_sample_size
           FROM hw1 r
          GROUP BY r.budget
       ) s
```

By using a query like this, as a rowsource, we can have the values returned by the query available in the outer query. A query used as a rowsource like this is  referred to as an "inline view". In the MySQL venacular, it's called a "derived table".

As an example of what that query might look like:

```
 SELECT t.budget
      , t.price
      , COUNT(*) 
      , s.budget_sample_size
      , COUNT(*)/s.budget_sample_size
   FROM hw1 t
   JOIN ( 
          SELECT r.budget
               , COUNT(*) AS budget_sample_size
            FROM hw1 r
           GROUP BY r.budget
        ) s
     ON s.budget = t.budget
  GROUP
     BY t.budget
      , t.price
```

---

Note: This example query relies on a MySQL-specific extension to `GROUP BY` behavior. Other databases would throw an error ("non-aggregate in SELECT list not in GROUP BY"). It only requires a small tweak to the query to get it to work in other databases... e.g. add a MAX() aggregate function... replace the `s.budget_sample_size` expressions with `MAX(s.budget_sample_size)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the articulate explanation and all the efforts. I do learn a lot.

Comment: There other query patterns that will achieve an equivalent result. For example, using a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. This answer only outlines one of the possible approaches, using an "inline view".

Answer (score 0):

Please change the name of the field **'count(*)'**
and maybe clarify your question
However

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT [count(*)] FROM hw1 WHERE budget like 'high' AND price like 'high') / 
 (SELECT SUM([count(*)]) FROM hw1 WHERE budget like 'high')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want to get all the ratio for all rows in table hw1, is it ok for me to use 'a%' and 'b%'?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide neither your original tables structure nor raw data source nor your query - here is my guess approach:

```
SELECT hw1.*, 
      count(*) count_price, 
      (count(*)/b.budget_all) price_share 
FROM hw1 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT budget, COUNT(*) budget_all
   FROM hw1 
   GROUP BY budget
) b
ON b.budget = hw1.budget
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there if I understood your answer correctly, I think you could do something like this

```
SELECT t1.buget, t1.price, t1.cnt, t1.cnt / t2.sumCnt
FROM myTable AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT buget, SUM(cnt) AS sumCnt
           FROM myTable
           GROUP BY buget) AS t2
ON t1.buget = t2.buget;
```

it's simple inner join statement and subquery will return result like this

```
  buget | sumCtn
  --------------
  high  |  42
  --------------
  low   |  316 
  --------------
```

etc...

sou you can do simple mats in select statement when join this with your table...

Also notice I change a little name of your column so don't be confused by that..

GL!

P.S. Here is [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76f88/6) to see how it's work...